# Compute gradients manually/later in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow model `f(x)` and I sometimes need its gradients and sometimes not, depending on the result of the forward pass. In order to save computation time, I only want to compute the gradients when I need them. If I stop the gradient computation using stop_gradient() or don't record them on a GradientTape, it seems like I can never obtain the gradients without computing the forward pass again. A simplified example of what I'm trying to do looks like this (in pseudocode):

```
x = 5
y = f(x)
if y > 0:
  compute_gradients(f, x)
```

Is it possible to accomplish this in TensorFlow and if so, how would I do that?

Comment: There is a way to do this, but presumably, `y` will be in batches, correct? If this is the case, do you want to not compute the gradient for some instances in the batch that satisfy a criteria but compute it for others, or do you want to aggregate the prediction and not apply a gradient at all for the whole batch based on that single value?

Comment: @gobrewers14 At the moment, `y` won't be in batches. In my case, `f(x)` is a probability distribution function and I want to use the Metropolis algorithm to draw samples from the distribution. Because this is a Markov Chain algorithm, I need to draw one sample after another, so unfortunately I can't work with batches. I then later perform a sum that involves the gradients of `f`, over all the `x` that were selected by the Metropolis algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can skip gradient updates with a simple conditional.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import test as test_lib


# network
x_in = tf.keras.Input([10])
x_out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x_in)


# optimizer
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-1)


# forward pass
def train_step(model, X, y, threshold):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_hat = model(X)
        # threshold = tf.math.reduce_mean(y_hat)
        loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.MSE(y, y_hat))

    if tf.math.greater(threshold, 1.0):
        m_vars = model.trainable_variables
        m_grads = tape.gradient(loss, m_vars)
        opt.apply_gradients(zip(m_grads, m_vars))

    return loss


# test cases
class SporaticGradientUpdateTest(test_lib.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.model = tf.keras.Model(x_in, x_out)
        self.X = tf.random.normal([100, 10])
        self.y = tf.random.normal([100])
        self.w_before = self.model.get_weights()

    def test_weights_dont_change(self):
        _ = train_step(self.model, self.X, self.y, 0.99)
        # get weights that shouldn't have updated
        w_after = self.model.get_weights()
        self.assertAllClose(self.w_before, w_after)

    def test_weights_change(self):
        _ = train_step(self.model, self.X, self.y, 1.01)
        # get weights that should updated
        w_after = self.model.get_weights()
        self.assertNotAllClose(self.w_before, w_after)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_lib.main()

# [ RUN      ] SporaticGradientUpdate.test_weights_change
# [       OK ] SporaticGradientUpdate.test_weights_change
# [ RUN      ] SporaticGradientUpdate.test_weights_dont_change
# [       OK ] SporaticGradientUpdate.test_weights_dont_change
```

Per your comment, it looks like your use-case is a little different than this example but should be adaptable to whatever you are trying to do.

In the example, I passed in the `threshold` as an arg so I could test both cases, but normally you would create it by doing something to the output of the network (like the commented out portion).

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I thought the GradientTape records gradients already during the forward pass and the tape.gradients() function just outputs them. Is this incorrect? If so, I probably don't understand the purpose of the GradientTape in the first place.

Comment: `GradientTape` is a context manager that "watches" operations executed under it so it can perform gradient calculations (if requested). The [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff) have a really nice write up on it.

Comment: Alright, I see. Then thanks again very much! Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I accepted your answer.